# Old children's book about teenage girl who helps foxes

Tags: identification-request

My mom (b. 1960) has long searched for this book she read in her childhood. She consulted with librarians and even wrote a letter to the *Toronto Star*, but none of the suggestions were it. She gave up in the '90s, so now I'm wondering if the Newfangled Technology of the Internet can help.

Details: It was a picture book (for children) about a teenage girl who finds a den of orphaned fox cubs and cares for them in the den, rather than taking them home. The illustrations were in pencil crayon or pastel style.

She believes it wasn't an old book back then, so it was probably published in the late '50s or '60s.

Comment: I've not come up with anything so far. Could you narrow things down for us a bit? What age group is the book aimed at? Usually books with teenage protagonists are not aimed at younger children, but if it is a picture book that suggests more 'early years'. Have you already searched online, what search terms did you try? Are there books which came up in your searches that you can discount for us? Basically anything about your search that saves us going over old ground.

Comment: @Spagirl Unfortunately, that's all the detail she can remember :( She did note the incongruity of a teenage protagonist and it being a picture book for kids. My searches yielded little: looking for books about girls helping foxes yielded only recent titles, looking for books from the '50s and '60s yielded only unrelated classics, and looking for "1950s book about girl who helps foxes" yielded sites telling me how to find old books (whence [this post](http://w1.loganberrybooks.com/stumpthebookseller/?p=6986)).